# LogCat appears for Motorola/Xiaomi but not for Nexus 9

Tags: android, eclipse, logging, logcat

I am using Motorola & Nexus 9 & Xiaomi devices for Android App Development .
Earlier `LogCat` were coming for all the three devices but suddenly when I upgraded my Nexus to Nougat from Marshmallow from that day `LogCat` is not coming when I use Nexus to run my application. For other 2 devices `Logcat` is working fine.
USB Debugging in on as it is getting detected in Eclipse.
What configuration I need to check in case of Nexus.

Comment: did you check through android device monitor?

Comment: Sorry, But did I heard eclipse! for android development!! @kalpit please switch to android studio for android development,Google doesn't support eclipse anymore.

Comment: @RushiAyyappa I am using logcat in eclipse.

Comment: @AnuragPandit I will in future but right now do you have solution for this problem

Comment: you should try in android studio. I think google has stopped support to eclipse.This may be a reason.I am not sure but give a try. because i use emulator with android 7.0 it works fine

Comment: @RushiAyyappa But the problem occurs as soon as I update my android version in nexus.. Before it was coming fine..

Comment: okay..do you know how to clear cache and restart in eclipse?

Comment: @RushiAyyappa Tried. If there was a problem in eclipse logcat It would not have worked for other devices

Comment: @Kalpit is my solution working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try to track it from DDMS tool from ADM:

```
open the directory "sdk-tools folder/tools/",

and double click monitor.bat.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had been through this problem, nothing works adb kill/start, android studio restart/invalidate-cache nothing.

I had to do factory data reset for my device then it worked.